# How to not display even one column is null in table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table like below:

[image]

I want result like even one column is null or empty string those records should not be display.

I want results like below:

[image]

Comment: its SQL server..

Comment: you have not much choice but to check for it `WHERE col1 IS NOT NULL AND col2 IS NOT NULL AND col3 IS NOT NULL AND . . . `

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from WHERE col1 IS NOT NULL AND col2 IS NOT NULL AND col3 IS NOT NULL AND col4 IS NOT NULL AND col5 IS NOT NULL....AND col9 IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Please add some description on what you do

Comment: I have table with 90 colums, if i wrote like this will get performance issue. Is there any alternative solution

Comment: @Thrilok . . . There is no performance issue with this construct, given what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted an efficient way to do this, then one method would be a persistent computed column:

```
alter table t
    add numNulls as ( (case when col1 is null then 1 else 0 end) +
                       (case when col2 is null then 1 else 0 end) +
                       (case when col3 is null then 1 else 0 end) +
                       . . .
                     ) persisted;
```

You can index this column:

```
create index t_numNulls on t(numNulls);
```

And then you can use this in the `select`:

```
select t.*
from t
where num_nulls = 0;
```

That said, I suspect that your real problem is the data model.  I am guessing that those 90 columns are really an "array" -- that is, all the same entity.  These should be implemented as separate rows in a junction table.